# Is there an easier way to update fields on a record based on the data from multiple lookup fields?

Tags: process-builder, object-model

I have a custom object on which I need to calculate bonuses for multiple users based on a bonus % that is stored on the users' records. Right now I have it working using 6 different Processes using Process Builder, but I am wondering if there is a more streamlined way to accomplish the same goal. Here is exactly what I have setup now;

I have 6 lookup fields on the custom object, each representing one of up to 6 people that can earn a bonus related to this record.

On the user records I have a custom field storing the bonus eligibility % for that user.

I am using Process Builder to grab the bonus % from the user record if the lookup field is not NULL. Currently, I have 6 Processes setup, one for each lookup and it's corresponding fields.

The Process also looks at the ADM Bonus field; if it is null it executes the Process. I did this so the user can edit the % in one-off cases where the bonus needs to be adjusted for a specific user.

Here is a screen shot of the fields being used; 
[image: Process Builder Question]

Is this the best way to complete this task, or can I simplify it somehow? Just hoping to learn how to be more efficient if possible.

Thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: Formulas? You could certainly consolidate it into one process, for however much that simplifies it.

Comment: Typically in this situation I would create a "bonus" object as a detail record with a lookup to the user. Then use a WFR to grab the current % from the user record and populate it in the bonus record (so if it changes on the user it doe snot affect historical records). Then use formulas to calculate the bonus. This provides the most flexibility and scalability. Your design is a typical pitfall of using multiple fields where detail records should be used

Comment: When I say "Detail with a lookup to the user" I mean a detail to your master record where the fields are now and the detail record will ALSO contain a lookup to the user record. You can then use a Roll Up summary field to total all the bonuses and apply it to the final revenue before taxes field

Comment: That's a great suggestion, Eric. Thank you. Unfortunately, in this situation I am limited by the license. I am working with an OEM Platform license, which doesn't allow for one-off creation of custom objects.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @AdrianLarson. Formulas won't do the trick because I need the ability to make one-off edits to the %. The Processes I've setup are working, so I may just have to run with it.